# Loading more than six chunks at once

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m making the Infinite IKEA (SCP-3008, look it up, it’s pretty cool), except that’s it’s a square kilometer in area (1000 blocks by 1000 blocks) instead of being infinite. Now, in the IKEA, the day/night cycle is simulated through the lights shutting on and off. Considering my ceiling (and the cannon ceiling, probably) is at build height, using lanterns is a no-go. Therefore, I have opted for command blocks that simply alternate between a glass and iron ceiling. I say blocks plural, because each command block manages a sector of a hundred square meters. When one activates, a chain command block activated the next module, and so on.

Now here is the problem. If the command block is manipulating blocks that are out of view, you will get an error message saying that “blocks outside the world cannot be accessed”. **Therefore, I need a way to load every chunk at once.** Ticking areas will not work, as they cover at most sixteen hundred square meters, and you only have 10. I’ve tried altering my render distance through the game files, but to no avail. **Is there a program that can either increase the ticking area’s power or force load many thousands of blocks? (A bit over a million).**

Preferably, I would want this solution to be accessible to mobile, but if this is not possible, then that is fine.

Comment: You seem to want to do more with Minecraft than just breaking and placing a few blocks. That's exactly the purpose of Minecraft, but sadly MCPE really isn't made for it. It lacks a lot of features from the original Minecraft and as soon as you do anything beyond the "normal" gameplay, you will run into issues like this. Believe me, it only gets worse from here. I recommend switching to Minecraft Java.

Comment: @Fabian Röling I would, but unfortunately, I do not possess a PC, and, while it might just be me being lazy, relearning everything controls wise, and even gameplay wise doesn’t appeal to me. I’d also have to relearn redetone, but I recognize the advantages. In a way, Minecraft Java and Bedrock are like Android and Apple. Java is more modifiable, but a bit less stable, compared to Bedrock, which is limited in modding, but more stable. (C++ is more stable than Java).

Comment: Minecraft Java isn't unstable. Same with Java and C++, those are just programming languages. And you can play Minecraft Java on every device that runs Java, which is almost every device, in theory at least. For Android, there is an app called "Boardwalk" that lets you play Java edition.

Comment: Java has some quirky things about it. First off, it’s apparently laggy and choppy at times. Secondly, what is up with the redstone in Java? You place two pistons on top of one another, then place a redstone block on top. Then break the top piston, and bam! The bottom piston powers itself.

Comment: Fair points. Against the lag you can play 1.12.2. Against the piston bugs only modding helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in the shower thinking about how to best implement a function, I stumbled across a possible solution for your problem: have many smaller command block chains that command a couple chunks around them. You could probably testfor a player and then set the blocks accordingly. The SCP you referenced will likely not have super large rooms, so you'd probably be able to get away with this system.

I'm going to keep my other answer up, because other Googlers will end up here, and because it will work in the future, but for now we're stuck with Vanilla mechanics.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure I understand. By “smaller chains of command blocks that command a couple chunks around them”, do you mean generate the map as the player walks around? Edit: I figured out a way to do the day/night cycle with your method. This answer will be marked as the “correct” one. The other one was good, but unfortunately inaccessible to me.

Answer (score 5):

In order for that to work, Minecraft would need to have a strong modding community.

Luckily for you Minecraft has one of the biggest modding communities. The mod you are looking for is called FTB Utilities. (There are other mods, but this one is closest what you want, I think). You will need a mod launcher, and this mod has a chunkloader utility that keeps chunks loaded. All these things should be easy to Google and set up, but if you need more guidance ask and I'll add to my answer.

One caveat: You will have to use the Java version of Minecraft, as that is the version that is modable. The Bedrock modding community is getting close, but not quite there yet. One interesting project to follow is https://nukkitx.com, perhaps you could ask their forums to see the plausibly or even solution of a chunkloader plugin at their stage.

Your save file will be compatible with Vanilla Minecraft if you switch back, but the chunks won't be auto-loaded anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your solution, but, from what I understand, your answer would not work with the bedrock edition, which is what I am using. Maybe I didn’t catch something?

Comment: Ok, after a little more research, I found https://nukkitx.com, which is an open source modable bedrock server, however the mods are simple, and I couldn't find a chunkloader plugin. Feel free to search the plugins yourself, mine search wasn't very robust.

Comment: What next? Am I supposed to download something?

Comment: I'm afraid what you are looking for isn't completely developed yet. But, when development is to the point of chunkloading, you would download the server on https://nukkitx.com, download a chunkloading plugin (when it gets made) or if you're lucky, see if there is a chunkloading setting in nukkitx itself. The next step would be to head over to the nukkitx forums and ask them, they would know better and give you better direction than a generic gaming Q&A forum such as Arqade. They might even have a fully developed solution I missed. Good luck!